# E-commerce building

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I´m starting with MySQL developing and consider to make my own e-commerce site.

1. If I want to store customer´s wish list in a table should I do it, like first column has user id and second has product ids separated like `product0|product1|product2` or is there some more effective way to do this in MySQL?
2. Should I store the user details forever, or remove them when the order has been processed?
3. Is this enough secure function to take off dangerous characters from user inputs:

   ```
   function siisti($str){
   $str = strip_tags($str);
   $str = htmlentities($str);
   $str = trim($str);
   $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
   $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
   $str = str_replace(array("&auml;", "&ouml;"), array("ä", "ö"), $str);
   return $str;
   }
   ```
4. Is there any other that I should look when creating it?

**EDIT:**
One more question
Is this good way to do the pages:

up.php

```
Content to be inserted top of all pages


 | Some Site
etc.
```

down.php
`Content to be inserted footer of all pages
some copyright notes etc.
<./body>
<./html>`

somepage.php

i.nclude("up.php"); 
some content here

In some  reason the code handling does not work at all! So just click edit to see what I have as code. This bug should really fixed in this site.

Comment: In some reason the code seems not to do as it should. I have added four spaces, but something is still wrong. Maybe someone fixes it.

Comment: the code block is doing that because it is part of a numbered list.  I tried to fix it, but failed.

Comment: I added new question. And tried to use <pre><code> tags. Dots are there for reason, to help code rendering

Comment: don't stick a new question on an old question.  Make a new question!  Read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Ok, i´m sorry for caused inconvience, I actually created new question for that case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use a table with columns `customer` and `product` and insert multiple rows for each customer - one for each product they own.

   ```
   +-----------+----------+
   | customer  | product  |
   +-----------+----------+
   | customer0 | product0 |
   | customer0 | product1 |
   | customer0 | product2 |
   | customer1 | product2 |
   | customer2 | product0 |
   +-----------+----------+
   ```
2. In general, do not delete rows. Just mark them as processed. This allows you to audit the system.
3. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` or parameterized queries when accessing the database. Use HTML escaping functions when writing HTML. There is no such thing as "dangerous characters", only "dangerous programming". **Never** try to write "cleaning" functions yourself. Using generic cleaning functions makes you lazy. You won't understand what you are doing and that will lead to mistakes.

Comment: And if the customer adds a new does it go like customer0 product 0 | customer1 product 2 | customer 0 product 3 . In here | states row change

Comment: Olli: Yes, the rows can be in any order.

Comment: and can I then fetch them using PDO `$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE customerid = ".$_GET['customerid']."");`

Comment: @Olli, NO! You are not using prepared queries correctly, and are **still** wide open to SQL injection.  You need to bind to a parameter rather than sticking client-defined variables directly in the query.  I certainly hope I never have to shop at your online store, as it will undoubtedly be hacked within a day of its opening.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: @Brad @Olli Yes, I will use this format: `$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE customerid = ?"); $query = $conn->execute(array($_GET["id"]));` Is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

1:  NO NO NO NO, don't do this.  Have a separate table for products, have a table called "cart" or something with two columns... one for customer ID and one for product ID.  Quantity and price-in-cart might be also useful to you.

2:  You have to store some data for later.  Do not store credit card information.  Read up on [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/).

3:  Do not do this.  You are mangling your data beyond repair.  Use the functions as necessary when they are necessary.

4:  Given the questions you are asking, and the fact that this wheel has been made 100 times over, stop now, modify an existing solution.

Comment: What HTML escaping function you would recommend? And why is it bad to make a cleaning function what I made? I think it´s very safe solution since it will take off all dangerous characters. I don´t want to have any dangerous characters or linebreaks in mysql DB.

What style should the wish list table be, I actually cannot understand your meaning

Comment: It isn't a safe solution.  When inserting things into the DB, use parameterized queries (look into PDO to make it easy), so you don't have to worry about SQL injection.  As far as avoiding XSS issues, it all depends on the context of how you use it, but escape the data when you use it, not prior to the database (for XSS).

Comment: It isn't a safe solution.  When inserting things into the DB, use parameterized queries (look into PDO to make it easy), so you don't have to worry about SQL injection.  As far as avoiding XSS issues, it all depends on the context of how you use it, but escape the data when you use it, not prior to the database.

Comment: @Olli: There is no such thing as "dangerous characters". It's your code that is dangerous.

Comment: hmm I looked PDO tutorial in a programming site. PDO seems to be very handy. So I can directly put any get/post variables there and don´t need to make any check for them? Like strip_tags or something like it? What function should I use when I print out example product details?

Comment: Brad - do you have answer to my latest question ?

Comment: @Olli, no need for "bump" messages, we get alerted when you reply.  Using parameterized queries with PDO means that you don't have to escape your data for SQL, as the data and the SQL query are sent separately, rather than inline like a traditional query.  You still need to remove other unsafe user input for other contexts.  If you were to echo out data directly from the browser, you open yourself up to XSS attacks.  So, when you use userdata, you need to be aware of the context and handle it appropriately.